# Why is Big $O(X^3)$ instead of Big $O(X^2)$ for this algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

The is the running time of an algorithm : $0.5 X^2 + 3X$ ,

Q1) i dont understand why my lecturer says that the Big O is $O(X^3)$, shouldnt it be $O(X^2)$ as it is bounded by the quadratic power of $X$.

Who is correct , me or my teacher ???

Q2) Why is the Theta of the equation : $X^2$, i cant understand why

Comment: Both you and your teacher are correct (isn't that nice?).
You say that it is $O(x^2)$ which is true. But anything that is
$O(x^2)$
is also  $O(x^3)$ since the $O(...)$ notation only fixes an
upperbound.
Things are different for $\Theta$ as it gives both an upperbound and a
lower bound. Clearly, your running time is $\Theta(x^2)$. It cannot be
$\Theta(x^3)$ as that would be too high as lower bound.

Comment: -1: You asked a very very similar question recently. If you understood the answers there...